# PHP reduce and merge? an array in several steps

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, reduce

I'm trying to reduce/merge an array looking like this

```
$test = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 150023
            [rowtext] => part 1
            [rowpartnumber] => 4360
            [qty] => 2.00
            [min_delper] => 2021-07-28
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 150026
            [rowtext] => part 2
            [rowpartnumber] => 4360
            [qty] => 2.00
            [min_delper] => 2021-07-29
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 150023
            [rowtext] => part 3
            [rowpartnumber] => 4361
            [qty] => 4.00
            [min_delper] => 2021-08-22
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 150023
            [rowtext] => part 4
            [rowpartnumber] => 4362
            [qty] => 2.00
            [min_delper] => 2021-09-22
        )

);
```

I want to sum the [qty] where [rowpartnumber] are the same, I can achieve this with

```
$summa_test = array_reduce($test, function ($a, $b) {
  isset($a[$b['rowpartnumber']]) ? $a[$b['rowpartnumber']]['qty'] += $b['qty'] : $a[$b['rowpartnumber']] = $b;  
  return $a;
});
```

But I would also like to take the [id] where [rowpartnumer] are the same and add it to [id]
so the output should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 150023 150026
            [rowtext] => part 1
            [rowpartnumber] => 4360
            [qty] => 4.00
            [min_delper] => 2021-07-28
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 150023
            [rowtext] => part 3
            [rowpartnumber] => 4361
            [qty] => 4.00
            [min_delper] => 2021-08-22
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 150023
            [rowtext] => part 4
            [rowpartnumber] => 4362
            [qty] => 2.00
            [min_delper] => 2021-09-22
        )

);
```

Can't seem to get my head around it, so a little help from you experts would be great, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the callback function to concatenate the `id` to the previous one if the `rowpartnumber` already exits. Like this:

```
$summa_test = array_reduce($test, function ($carry, $item) {
  if (isset($carry[$item['rowpartnumber']])) {
      $carry[$item['rowpartnumber']]['qty'] += $item['qty'];
      $carry[$item['rowpartnumber']]['id'] .= " ".$item['id'];
  }
  else {
      $carry[$item['rowpartnumber']] = $item;
  }
  return $carry;
});
```

I don't know whether it is a problem, but because of the concatenation `id` will become a string where multiple ids are found - but remains integer when only one. If it is a problem for you, there are two options:

- Convert to string even if only one `id`
- Use an array to store to multiple ids.

(I changed the parameter names to the ones used in PHP documentation - you can change it back, but generally it is a good idea to keep that way - others will more easily understand your code.)

Comment: Awesome, that is exactly what I was looking for, regarding the id its not going to be a problem if it's a string for me. And thank you for excellent educational explanation